# can not get correct results with group by in mysql

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have 2 SQL tables

```
CREATE TABLE A(
  id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE B(
  id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  A_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

INSERT INTO A VALUES (1, 'A'), (2, 'B'), (3, 'C'), (4, 'A');
INSERT INTO B VALUES (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 4), (4, 4);
```

The tables look this way:

```
select * from A;
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
|  1 | A    |
|  2 | B    |
|  3 | C    |
|  4 | A    |
+----+------+

select * from B;
+----+------+
| id | A_id |
+----+------+
|  1 |    1 |
|  2 |    2 |
|  3 |    4 |
|  4 |    4 |
+----+------+
```

Now I want to find out how many each of the elements from table A are there in table B. Using other words I want to see:

```
A = 3
B = 1
C = 0
```

I tried to do this with: `SELECT name, count(*) FROM A, B WHERE A.id = A_id GROUP BY A.id;`, but it returns something completely weird. Can someone help me?

Comment: Is that `A = 3` ? what logic is for `A = 4`

Comment: Sorry, A = 4. I will change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Query

```
SELECT a.name,COUNT(b.A_id) as `count`
FROM A a
LEFT JOIN B b
ON a.id=b.A_id
GROUP BY a.name;
```

### [Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e85f0/13)

Answer (score 1):

You should use a `LEFT JOIN`, and not `GROUP BY A.id`, but instead by `name`:

```
SELECT A.name, COUNT(B.A_id)
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON A.id = B.A_id
GROUP BY A.name;
```

Comment: This gives C = 1. It should be 0

Comment: My bad, typed too fast. Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

You just need a left outer join to handle the condition where there are no A's in B:

```
SELECT A.Name, COUNT(b.id)
FROM A
LEFT OUTER JOIN B on A.id = B.a_id
GROUP BY A.Name;
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e85f0/2)

Comment: Sorry that I can not accept 2 answers. Your answer is also correct. Thank you very much.